# pod not found in Mac

Tags: cocoapods

I have installed gem already but still not able to access pod command.

sudo gem install cocoapods

I am getting this error
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)
✗ CocoaPods not installed.
CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin
code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install see
https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for
instructions.